# JQuery Not Working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome

This code works properly in Firefox but not in Chrome, If you need more of the code I would be glad to provide it, a button changes a background image:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var bg = 1;
$("#changePic").click(function () {
    if (bg == 1)
    {
        $("#outerWrapper").css("background-image","url(images/background-lodge1.jpg");
        bg=2;
    }
    else if (bg == 2)
    {
        $("#outerWrapper").css("background-image","url(images/background-lodge2.jpg");
        bg=3;
    }
    else
    {
        $("#outerWrapper").css("background-image","url(images/background-lodge.jpg");
        bg=1;
    }
  });
});
```

I'm not getting any errors in the Chrome Console. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are not closing the url for the background

```
 $("#outerWrapper").css("background-image","url(images/background-lodge.jpg)");
                                                               was missing ^
```

Comment: +1, nice catch.  I looked at it again even after knowing what was wrong and still couldn't see that.... :-/

Comment: It was a bit tricky.  I'm kinda sad that ff handled it better than chrome though.

Comment: Really? I'm sad FF let him get away with it.

Comment: Yeah I'm surprised FF new what I meant, a bit disappointed there was no syntax error or any clue, thanks again Stefan, I'll mark correct ASAP

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, you can really factor out a lot of that common code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bg= 0;
    $("#changePic").click(function () {
        bg= (bg+1) % 3;
        var name= ["lodge", "lodge1", "lodge2"][bg];
        $("#outerWrapper").css("background-image", "url(images/background-"+name+".jpg)");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To see what javascript errors are there in chrome, press "ctrl+shift+I" and go to console tab. or "ctrl+shift+J" to go to Console tab directly.

[image]